# Store reference to parent document instead of storing copy of document

Tags: ravendb

In the classic case of Orders and OrderLines, each OrderLine has a reference to its parent Order.  When I save my OrderLine to RavenDB, it saves a copy of the full Order record as a property of each OrderLine.  How do I get it to save only the link to the Order instead?  Like this:

```
{ 
...other orderline properties...
Order : "orders/123"
}
```

instead of this

```
     {
        ...other orderline properties...
        Order : {
    ...all properties for order 123...
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to non-relational databases!  Order lines don't get ids.  They don't get put in their own documents.  They are stored where it matters - with the Order!

```
public class OrderLine
{
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLine> Lines { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

Produces documents like:

```
orders/123
{
    "CustomerId": "customers/456",
    "Lines": [
        { "Product": "Foo", "Quantity": 2, "Price": 10.00 },
        { "Product": "Bar", "Quantity": 3, "Price": 20.00 },
        { "Product": "Baz", "Quantity": 4, "Price": 30.00 }
    ]
    "Total": 200.00
}
```

See [the documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/theory/document-structure-design) for more.

Comment: Sure Matt, but even in the link you mention, the OrderLine section is storing a reference to its product, instead of storing a copy of all that product's properties.  How do I achieve that when my OrderLine class has a Product property of type Product? Would I have to change my OrderLine class to have a ProductID property of type string instead?

Comment: Consider that you want the product information in the order line to be exactly how it was at the time of the order.  If the product changes or is deleted, it shouldn't affect past orders or order lines.  So you should duplicate the fields from the product that you need into the order line.  You might want a `ProductId` for reference purposes, but you should probably denormalize the product description and price separately into the order line.  You might create a container class for this (ex, `ProductRef`), or you might just store the fields individually.

Comment: Also, read [this](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/handling-document-relationships)

Comment: And the answer is... it depends.  If you will always be showing all comments with your question (as is the case with many blogs), then you certainly would be better to store them all in one document.  You'd be loading them all anyway, so loading one document is better than loading hundreds.  Then again, if you plan on having hundreds of comments - you probably *wont* be showing them all at once, but rather paging through them.  In that case - each comment would be in it's own document with a reference back to the QuestionId.  RavenDB allows both options.  `Include` and `LoadDocument` can help.

Comment: I'd like to refer you to [the RavenDB Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ravendb) if you have additional questions regarding understanding modeling.  Let's keep Stack Overflow for specific code. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Matt...I see we had a timing difference here though...as I removed my comment to post it as a new question...I'll move this on to the Google Group though...